# Preview of Excel data visualized with XLSX and canvas-datagrid in AngularJS app not getting drawn neither in Chrome nor in IE11

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer, canvas, data-visualization

I got component in my app, which besides loading some initial data from server - when entering the certain state - has two buttons with labels "Preview File" and "Download file".
First button should execute method which will:
download from server .csv file - which is sent as an byte-array, thus it will be received as an ArrayBuffer - which then is converted to .xls spreadsheet and should be visualized in new, scaled, read-only window.

Second button should execute: downloading the same file, the same way and after converting it to .xls, make it be downloaded to local disk.

.csv manipulations are managed by SheetJS js-XLSX library and data visualization is managed by canvas-datagrid.

But the whole visualisation step is not working.

Here's the code:

```
previewFile(idx) {
  const file = this.files[idx];
  const fileName = file.originalFileName;
  this.getFile(fileName).then( (data) => {
    const arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(data);
    const sheetsObj = this.XLSX.read(arrayBuffer, {type: "array"});
    const sheetObj = sheetsObj.Sheets[sheetsObj.SheetNames[0]];
    const jsonObj = this.XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheetObj, {header: ["Some header1", "Some header2", "Some header3"], raw: false});
    const previewGrid = this.canvasDataGrid();
    previewGrid.data = jsonObj;
    this.$document[0].getElementById('grid').appendChild(previewGrid);
  });
}
```

And this code downloads and converts the data, but when trying to visualize, it shows black canvas rectangle, with default Chrome browser's crash icon:

[image: blank canvas rectangle]

And when I'm trying this on Internet Explorer 11, I'm getting this error in dev console:

```
SyntaxError: Syntax error
    at Grid (eval code:1:12155)
    at window.canvasDatagrid (eval code:1:13638)
    at Anonymous function (eval code:198:9)
    at processQueue (eval code:16383:11)
    at Anonymous function (eval code:16399:27)
    at Scope.prototype.$eval (eval code:17682:9)
    at Scope.prototype.$digest (eval code:17495:15)
    at Scope.prototype.$apply (eval code:17790:13)
    at done (eval code:11831:36)
    at completeRequest (eval code:12033:7)
```

But the docs of canvas-datagrid say it works perfectly fine on IE11.

What I want achieve with "Preview Button" is to be able to visualize the Excel spreadsheet in new window, scaled to, say, 1000px X 1000px, read only.

But no way don't know how to do it. Docs didn't helped me, looks like I'm too slow mentally, to figure this out faster by myself.

Anyone has experience with XLSX and canvas-datagrid and would like to help?

Answer (score 0):

I try to check your code and find that your code has '=>' [Arrow function] in it which is not supported by Internet Explorer.

[image]

This is the reason that it is showing syntax error in the console.

You need to transpiled your code from ES6 to ES5 which can work with Internet Explorer.

You can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile ES6 to ES5 code.

Reference:

[Arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)

I am not sure what issue your code has with Chrome browser.

Comment: No, it's not the issue, because I'm already using transpiler and the whole download of file and conversion are run even on IE11, but up to the grid visualization.
I think that call to `window.customElements` inside the minified file of canvas-datagrid lib is doing the whole issue. I'll try using more polyfills for IE11 and let's see if it will solve my problem.

Comment: Is there any sample code that we can try to run in IE? I am not getting any other idea about the issue from above posted code and with the error message.

Comment: But the `previewFile()` functions is the whole code you need to address, because the issue is in the `const previewGrid = this.canvasDataGrid();` and `this.canvasDataGrid()` is a reference to `window.canvasDatagrid` from [canvas-datagrid.js](https://github.com/TonyGermaneri/canvas-datagrid) library which is responsible for not working visualization of excel.

Comment: You had developed the code so you can relate to your code but we had never seen your code. so it is quite difficult for us to assume the issue with above code block. So that's why we require any sample that can produce the issue.

Comment: But I already showed sample. The reference to [window.canvasDatagrid](https://github.com/TonyGermaneri/canvas-datagrid/blob/master/dist/canvas-datagrid.js), thus `window.canvasDatagrid=function(e){return new Grid(e)}` is responsible for this SyntaxError error on IE11.

Comment: Does it mean that you found the cause for the issue?